# What's going on with this Wolfram Alpha matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, wolfram-alpha

I was computing the matrix exponential of

$$X = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

by diagonalization. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrix+exponential&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22MatrixExponentialCalculator%22%2C+%22matrixexp%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B%7B1%2C-1%2C0%7D%2C%7B-1%2C2%2C-1%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C1%7D%7D%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22matrix+exponential%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D) and [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-exponential-calculator/e%5E%7B%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D1%26-1%260%5C%5C%20-1%262%26-1%5C%5C%200%26-1%261%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%7D) both solve this problem correctly. After the diagonalization and taking the exponential of the diagonal matrix, the only thing left to do is to compute the product

$$e^X = Pe^DP^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}1&-1&1\\ 1&0&-2\\ 1&1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&e&0\\ 0&0&e^3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}\\ -\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{6}&-\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{6}\end{pmatrix},$$

and this is where I ran into a problem. Symbolab computes this multiplication and obtains the value of $e^X$ that I was expecting (and that Wolfram Alpha and Symbolab both reported earlier), that is,

$$e^x = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{2+3e+e^3}{6}&\frac{-e^3+1}{3}&\frac{2-3e+e^3}{6}\\ \frac{-e^3+1}{3}&\frac{2e^3+1}{3}&\frac{-e^3+1}{3}\\ \frac{2-3e+e^3}{6}&\frac{-e^3+1}{3}&\frac{2+3e+e^3}{6}\end{pmatrix}.$$

But when I tried the [same multiplication on Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+%7B%7B1%2C-1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C-2%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%7D%7D+.+%7B%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2Ce%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2Ce%5E3%7D%7D+.+inverse+of+%7B%7B1%2C-1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C-2%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%7D%7D), all of the entries were off by $1/3$rd. I checked to make sure that I had typed everything in right, checked what Wolfram Alpha gave for the inverse to see if it matched, etc., and everything else seemed right.

Am I doing something wrong? Does Wolfram Alpha not know how to multiply matrices or am I just making a simple mistake somewhere?

Comment: I get the constant term to be $({1 \over 3}, {1 \over 2}, -{1 \over 6})^T (1,1,1)$ so I believe the above is incorrect.

Comment: You wrote `{{0,0,0},{0,e,0},{0,0,e^3}}` in Wolfram Alpha but it should be `{{1,0,0},{0,e,0},{0,0,e^3}}`. The first entry is wrong. Here is the [corrected result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+%7B%7B1%2C-1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C-2%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%7D%7D+.+%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2Ce%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2Ce%5E3%7D%7D+.+inverse+of+%7B%7B1%2C-1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C-2%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%7D%7D).

Comment: @user1551 yup, that's it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user1551 pointed out in a comment, the answer was as simple as a missing $1$: If

$$D = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \textrm{then} \quad e^D = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & e & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & e^3 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \textrm{not} \quad e^D = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & e & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & e^3 \end{pmatrix}.$$